# How to get percentage of valid data per column according to an indicator in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruits': ["Apple", "Peach", "Cherry"] * 2,
                  '2012': ["10", "20", "30", "40", np.nan, np.nan],
                  '2013': ["1", "2", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I don't manage to get a percentage for all the fruits in 2012, and 2013.

Result expected are:

- Apple 100% in 2012, 50% in 2013.
- Cherry 50% in 2012, 0% in 2013.

Comment: Please clarify the question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets' try [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) + [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) on `level=0` to leverage the mathematical values of `True` and `False` to determine the sum of `True`/`False` values (`1`/`0`) divided by the length:

```
out = df.set_index('fruits').notnull().mean(level=0).mul(100)
```

```
         2012  2013
fruits             
Apple   100.0  50.0
Peach    50.0  50.0
Cherry   50.0   0.0
```

Optional [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas-dataframe-applymap) to apply format string:

```
out = (
    df.set_index('fruits').notnull().mean(level=0)
        .mul(100).applymap('{:.0f}%'.format)
)
```

```
        2012 2013
fruits           
Apple   100%  50%
Peach    50%  50%
Cherry   50%   0%
```

---

Or with [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) with [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) + [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
out = df.groupby('fruits').agg(lambda s: s.notnull().mean().mul(100))
```

`out`:

```
         2012  2013
fruits             
Apple   100.0  50.0
Cherry   50.0   0.0
Peach    50.0  50.0
```

Optional string format and add `%` symbol with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map):

```
out = df.groupby('fruits').agg(lambda s: s.notnull().mean()
                               .mul(100).map('{:.0f}%'.format))
```

```
        2012 2013
fruits           
Apple   100%  50%
Cherry   50%   0%
Peach    50%  50%
```

---

Breakdown of steps that occurs in `agg`:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'apple': ['10', np.nan, '20', np.nan, '30']})
```

```
  apple
0    10
1   NaN
2    20
3   NaN
4    30
```

`s` represents an arbitrary value passed to the `lambda` in `agg`:

```
s.notnull()
```

```
   apple
0   True  # 1
1  False  # 0
2   True  # 1
3  False  # 0
4   True  # 1
```

```
s.notnull().mean()
```

```
apple    0.6  # (1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1) / 5 => 3 / 5 => .6
dtype: float64
```

```
s.notnull().mean().mul(100)
```

```
apple    60.0  # 0.6 * 100
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the way different between `size` and `count`

```
out = df.groupby('fruits').count().div(df.groupby('fruits').size(),0)
Out[149]: 
        2012  2013
fruits            
Apple    1.0   0.5
Cherry   0.5   0.0
Peach    0.5   0.5
```